# Pesquisar substring em coluna

Tags: microsoft-excel

O que preciso é quase uma procv. Tenho uma célula com uma palavra e preciso pesquisar por essa palavra em uma coluna em outra planilha. Só que nas células dessa coluna existem várias palavras. 
Por exemplo, quero pesquisar na coluna A em qual linha aparece 'uva'.

COLUNA A
banana manga uva
laranja pera
maça melancia
goiaba limão

Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso funciona:

Os números da coluna A devem ser maior ou igual a sua lista na coluna D

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A formula na célula E pega a palavra que você inseriu na celula b2 e procura 
na linha da coluna D, se não achar coloca o numero 0 senão coloca o numero da 
linha da coluna A

```
=SE( ÉERRO( LOCALIZAR($B$2;C2;1));  0; A2)
```

Na célula E7 tem a seguinte formula:

```
=SOMA(E2:E6)
```

para devolver em que linha foi encontrada a palavra

e eu copio para célula C2

Pronto.

Comment: Não pude caprichar. Mas dá para você seguir dai.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta mas eu acho que não consegui explicar bem o que preciso.